# Does Haskell have a generic binary search function?

Tags: haskell, binary-search

I wonder if haskell has a generic binary search function that takes a compare function `f`, which will return `EQ` if it finds the value, and a start and end value to search from. `f start` returns `LT`, `f end` returns `GT`, and `f output` returns `EQ`.

```
binarysearch :: (a -> Ordering) -> a -> a -> a
```

For example:

```
binarysearch (\x -> compare x 100) 1 1000 == 100

binarysearch (\x -> compare (x * x) 900) 10 1000 == 30
```

Comment: The function needs another parameter: one that calculates a value in the middle of two other values

Comment: But there is indeed a package to perform such operations, for example http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-search